# Removing decimal digits in symbology using ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcpy, symbology, arcgis-pro

Whenever I perform the Summarize Within tool in ArcGIS Pro and use the graduated colors symbology on the resulting feature class, I end up with something that looks like this:

[image: Symbology]

Is there a way to remove all those zeros i.e. can I set the results to zero decimal places using Arcpy for ArcGIS Pro?

I know how to do it manually without arcpy but I would like to be able to do it using python so that I can implement it into a larger piece of script.

Comment: it looks like the input fields are Double-Fields, is that true?
You could just add a new field (as a long integer with arcpy.AddField_management and insert/calculate the values from the given field using python (then delete the old field). Would that be an option? If the input fields are integer fields, the results are without the zeros? There might be also other solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The break labels of the graduated colors symbology can be overwritten with arcpy:

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps()[0]
lyr = m.listLayers("layer_name")[0]
sym = lyr.symbology
if sym.renderer == "GraduatedColorsRenderer":
    breaks = sym.renderer.classBreaks
    for b in breaks:
        b_int = b.label[0:-7]
        b.label = b_int
lyr.symbology= sym
```

See [GraduatedColorsRenderer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/graduatedcolorsrenderer-class.htm) for reference. I don't have ArcGIS Pro and haven't tested the code above but the equivalent in ArcMap works fine:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current")
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "layer_name")[0]
if lyr.symbologyType == "GRADUATED_COLORS":
    c = []
    labels = lyr.symbology.classBreakLabels
    for l in labels:
        c.append(l[0:-7])
    lyr.symbology.classBreakLabels = c
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for; however, when I try the code I get the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
TypeError: 'ClassBreak' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: I've modified the code slightly, could you try it? `classBreaks` and its `label` property are read & write, so it should be possible to modify them.

Comment: I tried it and got the same error. However, I am only changing the `layer_name`. I'm a little confused on what you mean by modify `classBreak`

Comment: I've fixed one more error in my code. Sorry, I can't test it. Could you try again? What you want to do here is modify the `label` property of the `classBreaks` property of the `renderer` property of the `symbology` property of your layer... Can you follow along? :)

Comment: Sorry I'm having a hard time understanding. Is that something I do inside or outside of the code?

Comment: You're not using the last version of the code: `b_int = b.label[0:-7]`. The code IS modifying the label property, you don't have to do anything more than running it.